# Why do you not remove rep for users who received rep on off topic questions kept for historical reasons?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I really like to see the profile of the users who answer my questions if they have a lot of rep, because I might learn from a question that they asked or answered.

I see a lot of users who received rep on off-topic questions kept for historical reasons. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)

This question (and many others) has given a lot of rep to the asker and those who answer.

It might be unfair to remove rep from those guys, but questions before were easy to answer. Nowadays, it's harder for new users to get rep. So is there any way to make it a fair game for new users without making the old users angry?

Comment: The question you linked is a community wiki one, so users there don't earn rep from the votes anymore. It became that way one day after it was posted, so not many users earned much from it - just saying

Comment: Your point is still good though.

Comment: there are other questions sir

Comment: Because a few people who got rep for off-topic questions don't want to let a single point go and went on a major tantrum on [metase] in the past few days.

Comment: I'd be perfectly willing to support *keeping* the questions (in an altered display state), but *removing* this reputation. Sure, you'd get some people bitching, but you'd solve all the good arguments about keeping the useful content around for the good of the Internet. People will get over reputation, as long as the content is still visible.

Comment: As an addendum to Cody's comment, for every person I saw whining about their lost rep, there were four who just wanted to keep the deleted content.

Comment: Yes, I think the rep loss was just a temporary shock as a result of the massive change in the reputation system. Everyone predicted that would cause an uproar. The thing about *that* uproar is it will die down, and already has. It's unfortunate that the reputation system changes got intertwined with the deletion of old content. There is some intersection, but one was already starting to go on before the rep system changes. I don't think most people mean to connect them. Those that are most passionate about keeping useful content around don't care much about rep, they have plenty of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this boils down to the distinction being made between locked questions, and deleted ones.  Questions that are locked, like [strangest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature) have valuable content, and *used to* be on topic here at Stack Overflow.  They are kept because of the value of their content, but locked so that they don't interfere with the site or create broken windows.

The deleted questions (theoretically) have zero valuable content, and were *never* on-topic.  [Favorite programmer food](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92257/programmers-food) would be a good example—my favorite answer therein being [I like cake!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/108535/352552).

The view is that rep earned for legitimate answers that are no longer on-top shouldn't be taken away; rep for junk answers that were *never* on topic is ill-begotten, and the original authors should have no reasonable expectation about keeping it.

It sucks that people will lose rep, and it might seem unfair, but this rep really should never have existed in the first place.

**EDIT**

Per the [Shog's blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/), it looks like rep on deleted answers will not be removed, so long as the post had a score of +3 or more, and was visible for at least 60 days.

Comment: [I like cake!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jwTwG.jpg)

Comment: Rep on deleted questions is being restored, started a couple of hours ago on meta.  I suppose you can have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: @UphillLuge - cool.  And nice pun!

Answer (score -1):

**NO, the new users just have to adapt and be better. Whatever you do, don't make the old users angry.**

Comment: +1 for _Whatever you do, don't make the old users angry_ (not because that's fair but because of fun)

Comment: Ah, much better than your last answer. :P

Comment: @Robert, Yeh, I really hit the bold button harder this time.

Comment: Lance - aren't *you* an old user?  Is this meant to caution people against pissing you off???  :-)

Comment: @Adam, I didn't really intend it in a personal way.  Just a joke referencing his question.